# How to get days from date to date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, I want to get days from date to date. Example: from `2015/12/28` to `2016/01/02`, the result as

```
2015/12/28
2015/12/29
2015/12/30
2015/12/31
2016/01/01
2016/01/02

DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME = '2015-12-28'
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME = '2016-01-02'
SELECT BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE AS DAYS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>[`CTE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)</kbd>

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE = '2015-12-28'
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATE = '2016-01-02'

;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT @STARTDATE As dt
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(D,1,dt) AS dt
   FROM CTE
   WHERE dt < @ENDDATE   
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: Great, I'll find document about `CTE`

Comment: @BrianCrist added link for it

Answer (score 3):

[You could build a calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), which would probably come in handy down the road. Or you could use a loop.

```
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME = '2016-01-02'
DECLARE @DAY DATETIME = '2015-12-28'
WHILE @Day <= @ENDDATE
BEGIN
SELECT @DAY
SET @DAY = DATEADD(DD,1,@DAY)
END
```

Or for all of the days in one result set:

```
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME = '2016-01-02'
DECLARE @DAY DATETIME = '2015-12-28'
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (DATE DATETIME)
WHILE @Day <= @ENDDATE
BEGIN
INSERT @TABLE
VALUES (@DAY)
SET @DAY = DATEADD(DD,1,@DAY)
END

SELECT *
FROM @TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the dates in your WHERE clause. For example, WHERE date >=@STARTDATE AND date <=@ENDDATE. That should return the full date in your results.

Answer (score 0):

using [Numbers](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) table

```
select dateadd(day,n,startdate)
from numbers
where dateadd(day,n,startdate)<=enddate
order by n
```